# MVC display checkbox for weekday enum

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum DayOfWeekEnum
{
    None = 0,
    Monday = 1,
    Tuesday = 2,
    Wednesday = 4,
    Thursday = 8,
    Friday = 16,
    All = 31
}
```

And I want to display it in a asp.net mvc application in a form of a list of checkboxes.

I found this code:

```
@foreach (DayOfWeekEnum item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeekEnum)))
        {
            if (item > 0 && item <= DayOfWeekEnum.Friday)
            {
                @Html.Label("DayOfWeekEnum", item.ToString())
                @Html.CheckBox("DayOfWeekEnum", (Model.Availability.HasFlag(item)),
                    new {value = item})

            }
        }
```

However, it does not send the values back to the controller.

Model looks like this:

```
public class Teacher
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public Level Level { get; set; }
    public DayOfWeekEnum Availability { get; set; }
}
```

Controller looks like this:

```
    [HttpPost] 
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "id,User,Level,Availability")] Teacher
        teacher)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            serviceClient.AddTeacher(teacher);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(teacher);
    }
```

Comment: Please post your whole form and not just the foreach....

Comment: `Html.CheckBox("DayOfWeekEnum", ...` means your giving your chekboxes `name="DayOfWeekEnum"` - does you model have a property named `public List<DayOfWeekEnum> DayOfWeekEnum { get; set; }`?

Comment: You will need to create a view model with a series of `boolean` properties - `bool isMonday`, `bool isTuesday` etc. and in the controller, set the `enum` value based on the boolean properties

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
@Html.CheckBox("DayOfWeekEnum", (Model.Availability.HasFlag(item)), new {value = item})
```

to:

```
@Html.CheckBox("DayOfWeekEnum", (Model.Availability.HasFlag(item)), new {value = (int)item})
```

It should update your source code from:

```
<label for="DayOfWeekEnum">Monday</label>
<input id="DayOfWeekEnum" name="DayOfWeekEnum" type="checkbox" value="Monday" />
<label for="DayOfWeekEnum">Tuesday</label>
<input id="DayOfWeekEnum" name="DayOfWeekEnum" type="checkbox" value="Tuesday" />
<label for="DayOfWeekEnum">Wednesday</label>
<input id="DayOfWeekEnum" name="DayOfWeekEnum" type="checkbox" value="Wednesday" />
<label for="DayOfWeekEnum">Thursday</label>
<input id="DayOfWeekEnum" name="DayOfWeekEnum" type="checkbox" value="Thursday" />
<label for="DayOfWeekEnum">Friday</label>
<input id="DayOfWeekEnum" name="DayOfWeekEnum" type="checkbox" value="Friday" />
```

to:

```
<input id="DayOfWeekEnum" name="DayOfWeekEnum" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<label for="DayOfWeekEnum">Tuesday</label>
<input id="DayOfWeekEnum" name="DayOfWeekEnum" type="checkbox" value="2" />
<label for="DayOfWeekEnum">Wednesday</label>
<input id="DayOfWeekEnum" name="DayOfWeekEnum" type="checkbox" value="4" />
<label for="DayOfWeekEnum">Thursday</label>
<input id="DayOfWeekEnum" name="DayOfWeekEnum" type="checkbox" value="8" />
<label for="DayOfWeekEnum">Friday</label>
<input id="DayOfWeekEnum" name="DayOfWeekEnum" type="checkbox" value="16" />
```

And this should send the correct value.

Comment: How could that possibly bind to anything (except `object`). Assume the 1st and 3rd are checked - the form values would be `DayOfWeekEnum=1&DayOfWeekEnum=false&DayOfWeekEnum=false&DayOfWeekEnum=4&DayOfWeekEnum=false&DayOfWeekEnum=false&DayOfWeekEnum=false` - it would be meaningless

Comment: @StephenMuecke I get your point. But if he does not need to "bind" to anything this could be a solution. He can process the posted data and get the selected ids.

Comment: @SmartDev can you please tell how to process  the posted data?

Comment: Sorry, but it just wont work at all. OP needs a view model with a series of `boolean` properties (see my comment to the question). Then in the controller `DayOfWeekEnum dayOfWeek = model.IsMonday? DayOfWeekEnum.Monday: 0; dayOfWeek |= model.IsTuesay ? DayOfWeekEnum.Tuesday : 0;` etc

Comment: @CoroveiAndrei You can read it using something like this (not tested): `IEnumerable<DayOfWeekEnum> selectedDays = DayOfWeekEnum.Where(o => !(o.ToString() == "false")).Select(o => (DayOfWeekEnum)Convert.ToInt32(o));` where `DayOfWeekEnum` is the posted `string[]` value (ex: `false,1,false,false,8,16,false`). But @StephenMuecke has a point here. If you want to bind the posted data, maybe you should use another aproach.